# Android : Google Maps API V2 displays black screen ECLIPSE

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to show my current location on google maps but it displays black screen in the map fragment.

my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.edraky.tasksheet"
    android:versionCode="13"
    android:versionName="6.7" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.edraky.tasksheet.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.edraky.tasksheet.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.edraky.tasksheet.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/transparentlogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>      
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactUs_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_us" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutUs_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us_"
            android:noHistory="false" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomePage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome_page" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDpP-HMGNQCnFPnzODgTiJFXs00yirfhHE" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ContactUs Layout ( layout displaying the map )

Contact us layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.edraky.tasksheet.ContactUsActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homebutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/contactusicon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

contact us activity class

```
public class ContactUs_Activity extends FragmentActivity {
                GoogleMap mMap;
                GPSTracker gps;
                Double currLat;
                Double currLong;
                GMapV2Direction gmap;
                Button homebutton;
                TextView view1;

                @Override

                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_us);
                                homebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homebutton);
                                view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                view1.setText("Text Shown");
                                homebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                                onBackPressed();
                                                }
                                });
                                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                                mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
                                gps = new GPSTracker(this);
                                currLat = gps.getLatitude();
                                currLong = gps.getLongitude();
                                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(currLat, currLong);
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));    
                }
}
```

i included all the libraries and generated the API key

[image: API key]

output is shown below

[image: Output]

no error message is logged. what could possibly go wrong in displaying the map ?

Note : same code is working on another application with different API key ofcourse and map is displayed correctly.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**:The app was already published on google play store before adding the Maps SDK API,so is there any modifications that I should do considering that or its irrelative?

Answer (score 0):

Go to console.google.com
And generate a new API key with package name(com.package.app) same as in your mobile app and SHA1.

Get the new API key, replace in the code. Uninstall the app and re-run.

Comment: Thank you I've tried that but it didn't work,by the way the app was already published on google play store before adding the Maps SDK API,so is there any modifications that I should do considering that or its irrelative?

Answer (score 0):

Okey , so i am not using `FragmentActivity`, and this may not directly tell the solution.

But this code definitely works and shows map using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;


public class OrderMapFrag extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapView mMapView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_map, container, false);
        ........
        ........
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();

       try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        //setting initial elements in map if required after this , as map got initialized properly


    }
}
```

But I am not using exact same elements and permissions you use in Manifest. For me these are the used ones.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY API KEY"/>
```